# LINQ запрос для 4 таблиц из 2х баз данных

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Существует 2 базы данных:
1 представлена таблицами, где t_stand - основная таблица, а t_fio содержит Id сотрудников и их имена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и соответственно 2 (в ней находятся справочные таблицы, где содержится Id и словесное представление):
Например в таблице t_ans_code AnsCode = 1, а AnsStr = Операция выполнена успешно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача состоит в том, что на одном представлении нужно использовать данные из всех моделей. Было решено создать новую модель, которая включала бы все необходимые поля:

```
// Фамилия сотрудника (t_standModel ; t_fio)
public string FIO { get; set; }

// ID сотрудника (t_standModel ; t_fio)
public Nullable<int> HaspKey { get; set; }
    
// Тип сообщения (t_standModel ; t_stand)
public int MsgID { get; set; }

// Тип сообщения (слова) (t_typeModel ; t_msg_type)
public string MsgStr { get; set; }
    
// Дата помещения запроса (t_standModel ; t_stand)
public System.DateTime ReqDT { get; set; }
    
// Строка запроса (штрих-код или эл.номер изделия) (t_standModel ; t_stand)
public string ReqStr { get; set; }

//Наименование изделия (t_typeModel ; t_type_all)
public string Name { get; set; }

//Эл.номер изделия (t_typeModel ; t_type_all)
public string Number { get; set; }

//Штрих-код изделия (t_typeModel ; t_type_all)
public string ShtrihCod { get; set; }
    
// Xml файл запроса (t_standModel ; t_stand)
public byte[] ReqData { get; set; }
    
//Дата помещения ответа (t_standModel ; t_stand)
public Nullable<System.DateTime> AnsDT { get; set; }
    
// Код ответа (t_standModel ; t_stand)
public Nullable<long> AnsCode { get; set; }

// Код ответа (слова) (t_typeModel ; t_ans_code)
public string AnsCodeStr { get; set; }
    
// Не используется (t_standModel ; t_stand)
public string AnsStr { get; set; }
    
// Xml файл ответа (t_standModel ; t_stand)
public byte[] AnsData { get; set; }
```

Теперь стоит задача создать запрос на заполнение этой модели. И с этим проблема. Во первых при формировании запроса вида:

```
 var list = from stand in db.t_stand
            join user in db.t_fio on stand.UserID equals user.HaspKey
            join code in dbv.t_ans_code on stand.AnsCode equals code.AnsCode
            join message in dbv.t_msg_type on stand.MsgID equals message.MsqID
select new mainModel { FIO = user.FIO, HaspKey = user.HaspKey, MsgID = stand.MsgID, MsgStr = message.MsgStr, ReqDT = stand.ReqDT, ReqStr = stand.ReqStr, ReqData = stand.ReqData, AnsDT = stand.AnsDT, AnsCode = stand.AnsCode, AnsCodeStr = code.AnsStr, AnsStr = stand.AnsStr,AnsData = stand.AnsData};
```

возникает ошибка:

> he specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
> associated with different contexts

А во вторых, поле ReqStr в зависимости от значения поля MsgID содержит либо штрих-код (пример:12345678912345), либо электронный номер (пример:01Х12345678912345). Поэтому 1 поле из t_stand (ReqStr) нужно сравнивать с 2 полями из t_type_all ( Number и ShtrihCode).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать запрос для такой ситуации?

p.s. Первый раз работаю с linq и mvc, так что простите за возможную банальность вопроса.

Comment: Вы используете именно linq2sql или всё же EntityFramework? Какая именно СУБД используется? На кой ляд используются две БД?

Comment: База то какая у вас?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov . База MySql. Для создания моделей использую Entity Framework. Т.к. нужно создать новую модель, как-то данные нужно извлечь из 2х старых, знаю только 1 метод- запрос (в данном случае выбран linq). 2 базы использует заказчик, изменить структуру базы возможности нет.

Comment: @tym32167 MySQL

Comment: EF [не поддерживает](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a6093d7-c7ea-43ce-bd01-19c4b1fba724/joining-two-entity-sets-from-different-contexts?forum=adodotnetentityframework) объединение двух контекстов/БД. Как вариант, можно попробовать сырой sql-запрос: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31961207/5045688

Comment: может быть создать вьюху, которая бы использовала данные двух баз ? тогда и EF бы скушал.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, попробую)

Comment: @morphey83, можете уточнить, что вы имеете ввиду? Как было написано в вопросе, я совсем новичок в этом

Comment: @Violofan, я имею в виду _представление_ (view). Вот вводная [статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/47031/). В основе представления может быть практически любой sql запрос. В том числе кросс-базовый. EF позволит работать с такими представлениями как с обычными таблицами (в некоторых случаях даже для вставок и обновлений)